# Convertir JSON ARRAY A STRING

Tags: java, json, string

Tengo este método que es de una lista de productos

```
 public String ProductosFacturas() {

    float montoTotalf = 0;

    int productsize = ctPagar.getProductArraylistsize(onGo);

    //Crear Array de productos del carrito para pasarlos al servidor como pedido completado
    JSONObject Pedido = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray PedidoD = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject PedidoDL = new JSONObject();

    String pCode;
    String pName;
    Integer pQty;
    float pPrice;

    try{
        for (int j=0;j< productsize;j++){
            pCode = ctPagar.getProducts(j,onGo).getProductCode();
            pName = ctPagar.getProducts(j,onGo).getProductName();
            pQty = ctPagar.getProducts(j,onGo).getProductQty();
            pPrice = ctPagar.getProducts(j,onGo).getProductPrice();

            PedidoDL = new JSONObject();
            PedidoDL.put( "barcode", pCode );
            PedidoDL.put( "nombre", pName );
            PedidoDL.put( "cantidad", pQty );
            PedidoDL.put( "precio", pPrice );
            PedidoD.put( PedidoDL);

            montoTotalf = montoTotalf + pPrice;

        }
        Pedido.put( "Factura", PedidoD);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

    return Pedido.toString();
}
```

Y quiero que su respuesta sea una lista y no un JSONARRAY se muestra asi: [image: EJEMPLO]

Comment: Hola Andrea, ¿te refieres a un List<T> ? ¿actualmente se esta obteniendo como indicas en la imagen?

Comment: Si se indica como esta en la imagen, y quisiera que se viera en forma de lista ya que es una factura

Comment: en forma de lista te refieres a que los datos se muestren en un ListView o a que la información del Json se almacene en un List<>?

Comment: Se muestren en un TextView, bueno asi lo tengo configurado

Comment: De repente se podrían crear clases con una estructura similar al resultado para poder hacer luego una serialización de esas clases y obtener un JSON de acuerdo a lo que necesitas. Yo tengo algo similar pero para C#.

Comment: Me podrias explicar!